# Copy projects from git submodule to ADO repository

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, repository, git-submodules

I have an ADO repository which includes a GitHub repository as a git submodule.

Here is an example of .csproj file in ADO repo:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Repositories.ABC\Repositories.ABC.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Repositories.XYZ\Repositories.XYZ.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project references mentioned in .csproj - Respositories.ABC and Repositories.XYZ are a part of GitHub repository (git submodule).
Is there a way to copy the projects - Respositories.ABC and Repositories.XYZ from git submodule to ADO repository in the specified path so that build will not fail?

Here is my project structure:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my submodule structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should enable getting [submodules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#submodules):

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self  # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
  clean: boolean  # whether to fetch clean each time
  fetchDepth: number  # the depth of commits to ask Git to fetch
  lfs: boolean  # whether to download Git-LFS files
  submodules: true | recursive  # set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules
  path: string  # path to check out source code, relative to the agent's build directory (e.g. \_work\1)
  persistCredentials: boolean  # set to 'true' to leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch
```

However if you use private repos for submodules and do not keep them in Azure Repos you may check rather - [Alternative to using the Checkout submodules option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#submodules)

> In some cases you can't use the Checkout submodules option. You might have a scenario where a different set of credentials are needed to access the submodules. This can happen, for example, if your main repository and submodule repositories aren't stored in the same Azure DevOps organization, or if your job access token does not have access to the repository in a different project.
>
> If you can't use the Checkout submodules option, then you can instead use a custom script step to fetch submodules. First, get a personal access token (PAT) and prefix it with pat:. Next, base64-encode this prefixed string to create a basic auth token. Finally, add this script to your pipeline:

```
git -c http.https://<url of submodule repository>.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Bearer <BASE64_ENCODED_STRING>" submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Thank you! To get a clarification - if I have an ADO repo which includes another ADO repo as git submodule, I can use the first steps you mentioned correct?

Comment: Generally speaking yes. If they are on the same project then for sure. There could be some edge case when it is not possible using this method, but you should give a try.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I be adding the checkout step that you suggested above? Would that be in a yaml file within main ADO repo or in a yaml file within submodule? Also, let's say path to one of the projects in submodule is <submodule>/Service/Project/Repositories.XYZ. What should I specify as path in the checkout step? Please let me know.

Comment: It should be your first step in steps in your YAML file. By default it gets code to `C:\agent\_work\1` but it depends where normally submodule is in your main repo. Please ad this step `- pwsh: ls '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'` after checkout to see how your root folder look like.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to copy the projects - Respositories.ABC and Repositories.XYZ from git submodule to ADO repository in the specified path so that build will not fail?

I am afraid there is no such way to copy the Github submodule to ADO repository **in the specified path**.

When we add the submodules to ADO repository, it will create two files in the ADO repository `.gitmodules` and project name file:

[image]

If we check out the submodules, git will save the project to the project name folder based on the path in the `.gitmodules`. Since the files `.gitmodules` and project name file are add in the source control, it checkout by default. If we want to change the path, we have to change the path manually after checkout.

To make sure the build successfully, we just need to make sure the path of `ProjectReference` in the `.csproj` file match the file structure in the repo.

**Update:**

If the directory hierarchy where your `Cleaner.csproj` file is located is like this `Service\Project\Hosts\Cleaner\Function\Cleaner.csproj`, the path should be:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\crypto-project\Service.xxxx\Repositories.ABC\Repositories.ABC.csproj" />
```

The path should be the relative position of `Cleaner.csproj` and `.gitmodules` file, a `..\` represents the upper level directory, and the path behind `..\` should be `crypto-project` + each level of directory folder.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give an example of how the path of ProjectReference should change in Main.csproj file?

Comment: Thank you! In my example, .csproj file in ADO repo has 2 project references - Repositories.ABC.csproj & Repositories.XYZ.csproj (which are in git submodule). How do update the path? Please give an example.

Comment: @user989988, the path related your file structure in the repo, would you please share the file structure in the repo like me in the answer (including mian.csproj and Repositories.ABC & Repositories.XYZ files).

Comment: @user989988, Is the `.gitmodules` file in the Cleaner folder? If yes, then the path should be `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\crypto-project\Service.xxxx\Repositories.ABC\Repositories.ABC.csproj" />`. The path should be the relative position of `Cleaner.csproj` and `.gitmodules` file, a ..\ represents the upper level directory, and the path behind ..\ is `crypto-project` + each level of directory folder.

Comment: No it's in the root folder - I have added one more image to make project structure more clear. Also, could you please add your answer as a part of solution instead of comment to be more clear? Thank you!

Comment: @user989988, I have updated the answer, please check if it helps you.

Comment: Than you! yaml file should have a step - checkout: self submodules: true correct?

Comment: @user989988, Right! But you may encounter authentication problem. Just do and check the result and let me know for free.

Comment: I updated project reference: <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\crypto-project\Service\Project\Repositories.ABC\Repositories.ABC.csproj" /> however it gives error: Unable to find project information for 'C:\Users\<user-name>\Desktop\submodules\<repo-name>\crypto-project\Service\Project\Repositories.ABC\Repositories.ABC.csproj'. If you are using Visual Studio, this may be because the project is unloaded or not part of the current solution so run a restore from the command-line. Otherwise, the project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.

Comment: @user989988, If I build with Visual Studio task, I get the same error as you. You could try to use MSBuild to build the main.csproj file directly, I could build it successful on my side. But we seem to have overlooked an important foundation, add a ProjectReference to a project that is not in the same solution is not recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314094/how-to-reference-a-project-out-of-solution and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601950/adding-a-projectreference-to-a-project-that-is-not-in-the-same-solution

Comment: I see - instead of updating project references in .csproj, is there a different approach for a success local build maybe without using git submodule?

Comment: @user989988, If you do not have any specific restrictions on the referenced projects, my personal suggestion is to add these two projects to your current solution, and then directly use the project reference, everything will become simple and proficient